# How can Mongoose "delete" non-existing documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Code:

```
function deleteItem(req, res) {
    Goods.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({
        success: false,
        error: err
      });
    } else {
      res.send({
        success: true,
        item: req.params.id
      });
    }
  })
}
```

If I pass an `_id` of just deleted document - Mongoose successfully "deletes" it.
If I pass an `_id` of never existed document, like `591dad9a1583ea0d1065d633` - it also "deletes" it.

Error throws only if pass trash like `a34pnv530eargdzbs`.

Could somebody tell me, what's going on, please ? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you check the related Mongoose documentation you will find the reason behind it:

> Finds a matching document, removes it, passing the found document (if any) to the callback.
>   http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove

If the document doesn't exist in your database Mongoose wont throw an error. You should check the 2nd parameter of the callback:

```
Goods.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, doc) {
  if(err || !doc) {
    // Show an error page
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you mean `if(err || !doc)`, no?